# Counting polyominoes on (hyper-)cubes

Tags: code-golf, geometry, combinatorics, polyomino

This challenge like some of my [previous](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/200122/53884) [challenges](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/187763/53884) will have you counting free [polyforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyform), which are generalizations of Tetris pieces.

This [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge will have you count polyomino-like polyforms on hypercubes. In particular, this challenge is to write a program that takes in three parameters:

- `n`, which represents an \$n\$-dimensional hypercube,
- `m`, which represents \$m\$-dimensional faces of the hypercube, and
- `k`, which represents the number of cells in the polyform,

and outputs the number of ways to choose \$k\$ (\$m\$-dimensional) faces on the \$n\$-cube such that the \$m\$-faces are connected at \$(m-1)\$-faces. These polyforms are "free" which means they should be counted up to the rotations/reflections of the \$n\$-cube.

Again, this is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so shortest code wins.

---

## Example 1

Okay, this is all very abstract, so this warrants an example.

When `n=3`, we're talking about the \$3\$-dimensional (ordinary) cube. When `m=2` this means we're talking about the \$2\$-dimensional (square) faces. And we're talking about `k` of these, joined along \$1\$-dimensional faces (edges).

When `k=3`, there are two such polyforms (on the left) up to rotations/reflections of the cube. When `k=4` there are also two polyforms (on the right).
[image]

## Example 2

In this second example, `n=3` still, so we're again talking about the \$3\$-dimensional (ordinary) cube. When `m=1` this means we're talking about the \$1\$-dimensional faces (edges). And we're talking about `k` of these, joined along \$0\$-dimensional faces (corners).

When `k=4` there are four such polyforms.
[image]

---

## Data

```
n | m | k | f(n,m,k)
--+---+---+---------
3 | 2 | 3 | 2       (Example 1, left)
3 | 2 | 4 | 2       (Example 1, right)
3 | 1 | 4 | 4       (Example 2)
2 | 1 | 2 | 1
3 | 0 | 0 | 1
3 | 0 | 1 | 1
3 | 0 | 2 | 0
3 | 1 | 3 | 3
3 | 1 | 5 | 9 
3 | 1 | 6 | 14
3 | 1 | 7 | 19
3 | 1 | 8 | 16
3 | 1 | 9 | 9
3 | 3 | 0 | 1
3 | 3 | 1 | 1
3 | 3 | 2 | 0
4 | 1 | 4 | 7
4 | 1 | 5 | 21
4 | 1 | 6 | 72
4 | 1 | 7 | 269
4 | 1 | 8 | 994
4 | 1 | 9 | 3615
4 | 2 | 3 | 5
4 | 2 | 4 | 12
4 | 2 | 5 | 47
5 | 1 | 4 | 7
5 | 1 | 5 | 27
5 | 2 | 0 | 1
5 | 2 | 1 | 1
5 | 2 | 2 | 1
5 | 2 | 3 | 5
5 | 2 | 4 | 20
5 | 3 | 4 | 16
5 | 3 | 5 | 73
5 | 4 | 4 | 3
6 | 1 | 6 | 121
```

Comment: I'm counting `f(4,1,6) = 72`, `f(4, 1, 7) = 269`, `f(4,1,8) = 994` with all the other test cases being correct. Is this an error in the test cases? I also get `f(4, 1, 9) = 3615` so I think those test cases might be off-by-one on `k`.

Comment: You're absolutely correct—I had an off-by-one in the data table. Sorry about that. It's corrected now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Python 3, 389

```
import itertools as I
S=sorted
P=I.product
def C(n,m,k):
 Q=[((-1,)*(n-m)+(0,)*m,)]
 for i in' '*(k-1):Q=set(tuple(S(q+(v,)))for q in Q for v in P(*[(-1,0,1)]*n)if sum(map(abs,v))==n-m if not v in q and any(sum((a!=b)*(1+2*a*b)for a,b in zip(v,u))==2for u in q))
 return sum(all(S(q)<=S(zip(*r))for X in I.permutations(zip(*q))for r in P(*((p,tuple(-x for x in p)) for p in X)))for q in Q)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZVTBbuIwED3XXzHVHmKHgEigsFSb0556a9WuVImtKgPuNiJxQuy0sOq/0xkncUE9GOfNPM@8NySuDva11JPjMSuqsraQWVXbsswNSAM37D41GFUbdpvejKq63DRryzbqBX5zHRXRVlwzuEuXnA/jSIRcDwsx4GN8LCLxxOClrCGDTAcQhHw7jMX1XWqU5bapcsXv@W7A3yIhBPF2yIM7d@SNHm95uKSy4ygWT6EW2QuYpuCFrLhcmehNiDTFfoBxXdr2zA6k3uA6cKJyeZmuUFU8SEIZrlwXGa2I@D@rsHNDNRIKN@60EAxqZZtau1Yyz0mj@JXeczoQ1q3SRyLjOFRdNFbarNSmze/afN3J57yKWqfDvfO1p0QlhAMVgccz8@Ko9rLAA@bZ2BpSCIJgAh@Q4HI769HUo7hDU5Z0yO0uN@7WF4rPEDHHvgrtE4@ucC3AwxntUw/ntC88/En7zMMFLYcmZwomZwomXsH0xMfcI1KQxA72A7jyyJESdtXXcFV7FJ@h5Ay5MjhXxn6AfVVGwXtZb2HVWJC1ApOX7yNGv8/f/4vZ6TA6af00ktnCYxrHYjH1mPjzVqw3NveKnKWxd0bh6dyT3Uw6vX/0uiwKpa17gUgk9CJHmH54VQfnJnJ20N0hyHOwcqtAwrqkVxGKTDfW8c/8DdDgX/xOB/DNO2M9wiksl5m2fC@@3uc802pkqjyzPPgIxJPLUJCSp3V6ErbBu4ERrUufMq/ZRVVTj@BBGZvpf0HUpQS7cHcO4kqt8VJCOV2KXci1bWSOkf5iwpAxeJfBFzuFluU73CLlMhA9FsdP)

Basically just finds all connected polyominos, and discards ones which can be rotated into a lexicographically smaller polyomino, with rotations being brute-forced.

Can definitely be improved but it's my bedtime.

Comment: I’m impressed! This is shorter than what I thought anyone would come up with!