# Polygons in a cube

Tags: code-golf, sequence, geometry, combinatorics, grid

Inspired in part by [this
Mathologer video on gorgeous visual "shrink" proofs](https://youtu.be/sDfzCIWpS7Q?t=799), and my [general interest](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/204419/53884) [in the topic](http://oeis.org/wiki/User:Peter_Kagey), this challenge will have you count regular polygons with integer coordinates in 3D.

You'll be provided an input `n`, which is a non-negative integer. Your program should find the number of subsets of \$\{0, 1, \dots, n\}^3\$ such that the points are the vertices of a regular polygon. That is, the vertices should be 3D coordinates with nonnegative integers less than or equal to \$n\$.

#### Examples

For \$n = 4\$, there are \$2190\$ regular polygons: \$1264\$ equilateral triangles, \$810\$ squares, and \$116\$ regular hexagons. An example of each:

- Triangle: \$(1,0,1), (0,4,0), (4,3,1)\$
- Square:   \$(1,0,0), (4,3,0), (3,4,4), (0,1,4)\$
- Hexagon:  \$(1,1,0), (0,3,1), (1,4,3), (3,3,4), (4,1,3), (3,0,1)\$
  [image: Animated GIF of a triangle, square, and hexagon embedded into the grid.]

The (zero-indexed) sequence begins:

```
0, 14, 138, 640, 2190, 6042, 13824, 28400, 53484, 94126, 156462, 248568, 380802, 564242, 813528, 1146472, 1581936, 2143878, 2857194, 3749240, 4854942, 6210442
```

#### Rules

To prevent the most naive and uninteresting kinds of brute-forcing, your program must be able to handle up to \$a(5) = 6042\$ on [TIO](https://tio.run/).

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, so the shortest code wins.

---

This is now on the On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences as [A338323](https://oeis.org/A338323).

Comment: So the gist of the video is that we'll ever have only regular 3/4/6-gons made of 3D grid points, however large the grid is, right?

Comment: @Bubbler—that's right!

Comment: I conjecture that the squares only appear on the planes parallel to the cube's faces, and the triangles and hexagons only appear on the (1,1,1)-lattice equivalents. Is this true?

Comment: @Bubbler, I've edited the example of the square to provide a square that is not parallel to a face.

Comment: @Bubbler, for a triangle, see \$(0,4,0),(1,0,1),(4,3,1)\$.

Comment: this is now https://oeis.org/A338323

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <strike>330</strike> 313 bytes

```python
import numpy as N,itertools as I
L=list
D=N.dot
n=input()
def G((a,b,c)):
 A=a
 while 1:
	u=b-a;v=c-b;d=D(v,v)
	if D(u,u)-d:return 0
	p=2*D(u,v)*v
	a,b,c=b,c,c+a-b+p/d
	if(p%d|(c<0)|(c>n)).any()or L(a)<L(A):return 0
	if L(a)==L(A):return 1
print sum(map(G,I.permutations(N.indices((n+1,)*3).reshape(3,-1).T,3)))/2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBNi4MwEIbP5lfksjBTo62VvdhmoVAoBfG0fyCaFAOahHy4FPa/d3VPPczAPPA@A697xtGa4@ulZ2d9pCbN7klFoB3TUflo7RS2805aPukQyZV3pbSRGK6NSxGQSPWgNwDBejYgNoReuCD0Z9STolVDssT7QpwWPhT9SfIrLGxBkukHvUJiCQvZeBWTN/RAMsePuw0vuFtI9q/k67AhF0Wfu73cguA@5C8M5wOu@8sglsI8Aa2nLQg8t3DBN@X6aMOcv/OKOK9NpCHNMAsHN3YvnfJziiJqawJ0pTZSDyoAmLxiuKux9CqMwimoWVFh@c1qRNyv1X3@AQ)

TIO spent `36.893 s` calculating `a(5) = 6042`, so this solution is just fast enough.

Given 3 consecutive points of a regular polygon `a,b,c`, the next point is `d = c + a - b + 2*proj(b-a, c-b)` (where `proj` is vector projection). My solution iterates through all triples of points and determines if they form a polygon using this formula.

Verified up to `a(7) = 28400` on my machine.

-17 bytes from ovs

Comment: You can get the coordinates a little shorter using pure numpy: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZDPisIwGMTPzVPksvB9bVqtxYuaBUEQofS0L5A2kQZsEvKni7Dv7rZ7WDzMYX4wMzDuGUdrdq@Xnpz1kZo0uScVgXZMR@WjtY@w2htp@UOHSC68q6SNxHBtXIqARKo7vQII1rMB8UDomQtCv0f9ULQ@kCzxvhTHmQ9lf5T8AjObkWT6Ti@QWMJSHryKyRu6JZnju3zFM@Yzyf4q@SI2FKLsC7eRaxDch8RKmCeg9QDDaYs/MHwa/Ie0BYGnFs741r0srpjzd14T57WJNKQJJuHgym6VU35KUURtTYCu0kbqQQUAU9QM8wYrr8IonIKGlTVWX6xBxM3y4f4X "Python 2 – Try It Online"). See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30335589/6346504) for details.

Comment: And `(p%d|(c<0)|(c>n)).any()` saves a few more bytes